API Call through URLSession
APIManager class:
import Foundation
import UIKit

class APIManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    private override init() {}
    
    func createURLRequest(method: HTTPMethod, url: String, queryParams: [(name: String, value: String)]?, headers: [(name: String, value: String)]?, body: Any?) -> URLRequest {
        
        var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: url)
        
        urlComponent!.queryItems = []
        if let queryParams {
            for queryParam in queryParams {
                urlComponent!.queryItems?.append(URLQueryItem(name: queryParam.name, value: queryParam.value))
            }
        }
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: (urlComponent?.url)!)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.key
        
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        if let token = TokenManager.shared.token {
            urlRequest.setValue("Token", forHTTPHeaderField: token)
        }
        
        if let headers {
            for header in headers {
                urlRequest.setValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.name)
            }
        }
        
        if body != nil {
            urlRequest.httpBody = getFormBody(body as? [String: String])
        }
        
        return urlRequest
    }
    
    private func getFormBody(_ parameters: [String: String]?) -> Data? {
        let arr = parameters?.map { (key, value) -> String in
            key.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!
            + "="
            + value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!
        }
        return arr?.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8)
    }
    
    func request<T: Codable>(endpoint: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: [(name: String, value: String)]? = nil, headers: [(name: String, value: String)]? = nil, body: Any? = nil, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let url = "\(Endpoint.shared.baseURL)\(endpoint)"
        let req = createURLRequest(method: method, url: url, queryParams: parameters, headers: headers, body: body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                        completion(.success(decodedResponse))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 401 {
                TokenManager.shared.fetchToken { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(_):
                        self.retryRequest(endpoint: endpoint, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, body: body, completion: { (result: Result<T, Error>) in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let response):
                                completion(.success(response))
                            case .failure(let error):
                                completion(.failure(error))
                            }
                        })
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                        completion(.success(decodedResponse))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    private func retryRequest<T: Codable>(endpoint: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: [(name: String, value: String)]?, headers: [(name: String, value: String)]?, body: Any?, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let url = "\(Endpoint.shared.baseURL)\(endpoint)"
        let req = createURLRequest(method: method, url: url, queryParams: parameters, headers: headers, body: body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(decodedResponse))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

EndPoint class
import Foundation

enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case put = "PUT"
    case post = "POST"
    case delete = "DELETE"

    var key: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}

enum Environment: String {
    case development
    case preProduction
    case production
}

class Endpoint {
    static let shared = Endpoint()
    
    private init() {}
    
    let currentEnvironment = Environment.development
    
    var baseURL: String {
        switch currentEnvironment {
        case .development:
            return ""
        case .preProduction:
            return ""
        case .production:
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    static var addressList = ""
}

TokenManager class to fetch authentication
import Foundation

class TokenManager {
    static let shared = TokenManager()
    
    private init() {}
    
    var token: String?
    
    func fetchToken(completion: @escaping (Result<TokenResponse, Error>) -> Void) {
        let tokenEndpoint = "https://api.example.com/refreshToken"
        let request = APIManager.shared.createURLRequest(method: .post, url: tokenEndpoint, queryParams: nil, headers: nil, body: nil)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(TokenResponse.self, from: data)
                        TokenManager.shared.updateTokens(token: decodedResponse.token)
                        completion(.success(decodedResponse))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func updateTokens(token: String) {
        self.token = token
    }
}

struct TokenResponse: Codable {
    let token: String
    let message: String
}

API Call From view model
class AddressViewModel {
    
    var addressList: Address?
    
    
    func fetchAddress(endPoint: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Address, Error>) -> Void) {
        APIManager.shared.request(endpoint: endPoint, method: .get, completion: { [weak self] (result: Result<Address, Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let address):
                self?.addressList = address
                completion(.success(address))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        })
    }
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Also, can you explain what the problem is? Code alone is insufficient. We need to know what behavior you were expecting and what went wrong.

Please edit your question to explain what your problem is .
